# New version of our software gets SmartScreen warning even though the file is signed

Tags: c#, digital-signature

We built a new version of our software, the file is signed but Windows SmartScreen still show this message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zx5fS.png

Microsoft Defender SmartScreen prevented an unrecognized app from starting. Running this app might put your PC at risk.

What does SmartScreen require to not show this message?

Thank you

Comment: Is everything signed with the right names \ credentials

Comment: SmartScreen works with a reputation system (It takes into account the count of installation etc.). New file no reputation even if the exe is signed. There is something called an Extended Validation Certificate that can circumvent that. But you need a different code signing certificate for that.